# Is there any mode for Rails' *.js.erb in emacs or I must use TextMate?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, emacs

I googled for "emacs js.erb" and got nothing valuable, Now I use web-mode for it, but obviously web-mode is not for `*.js.erb`:

1. it can not auto complete the html tag, such as `</div>`.
2. For `<% ... %>`, `<%= .. %>` and so on, it can not indent them.
3. For javascript code, it also can not indent them

So I want to ask whether there is other mode especially for `*.js.erb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it can; use `web-mode-element-close`, bound to `C-c C-e /` by default.
2. [This issue in `web-mode`](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/415) may be of interest to you.
3. Indentation works for Javascript in `web-mode` when it is enclosed within `<script>` tag.